# How to edit X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-originalarrivaltime?

Tags: email, microsoft-exchange

I want to edit the time in the file so it looks as if the email was sent at an earlier time on my computer.

Is it possible to edit X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-originalarrivaltime?

Comment: any luck doing that

Comment: @Lucky No, I never found out a way

Comment: Is your problem related to reply/forward where email DateTimeSent is displayed incorrect to the user who sent the email.?